# Android my bottom app a bar is overlapping my recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, android-mvvm

I am trying to fix this issue where my recyclerview is overlapped by bottomappbar. Here is my layout code .

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/notes_container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/myTasksHeader"
            android:textColor="@color/appBarTextColor"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                tools:listitem="@layout/note_list_item" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:hideOnScroll="false"
        app:menu="@menu/appbar_menu"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_note_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/medium_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when I fill my list I cant reach my last item in the recycler view. I tried adding margin but it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to achieve this

1. Hide `BottomAppBar` layout while scrolling ..

   Add following attribute inside `BottomAppBar`

   ```
           app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
           app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
           app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="10dp"
           app:hideOnScroll="true"
   ```
2. If you do not want to hide BottomAppBar then add margin from bottom
   in `RecyclerView`

   ```
   android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using margin is that the RecyclerView won't show through the FAB. A better solution than using margin would be to add extra space at the bottom of the RecyclerView using padding.

```xml
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="?actionBarSize"
```